# T-SQL allocate 10,000 invoices to each customer

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to prepare some test data and strugging.

I have the following invoice table with 500,000 invoice for each companyId (Assume there are 10 companies with 5,000,000 rows divided)

```
CREATE TABLE Invoice (
    InvoiceId INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    CompanyId INT NOT NULL,
    Amount INT NOT NULL,
)
```

Following is my customer table each company has 10,000 customers.

```
  CREATE TABLE CompanyCustomer(
        CustomerId INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
        CompanyId INT NOT NULL,     
    )
```

Finally, we have the customer invoice table. ***I want to allocate 10,000 invoices to 50 customers from each company. This is where I am struggling***. Since, each company has 500,000 invoice we can divide that into 50 customer and each user will get 10,000 invoices assigned.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.CustomerInvoice(
    CustomerId INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    CompanyId INT NOT NULL,
    InvoiceId INT NOT NULL,
)
```

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Comment: sorry, I have highlighted the question in bold

Comment: If you've solved issue with spreading invoice among companies what's the problem with performing absolutely same task for clients?

Comment: Hello Ivan, I am just preparing this for test data needed for load testing. In prod, we have c# code that does the allocation when every a invoice in created.

Comment: Sorry, but you still haven't asked a question, you merely stated your goal. As SO is not a code writing service, you should ask a specific question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can assign row numbers to the customers and the invoices, and use some simple maths to match them up:

```
INSERT INTO CustomerInvoice (CustomerId,CompanyId,InvoiceId)
SELECT cc.CustomerId,cc.CompanyID,i.InvoiceID
FROM
(select *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CompanyId ORDER BY InvoiceId) as rn
from Invoice) i
inner join
(select *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARITION BY CompanyId ORDER By CustomerId) as rn
from CompanyCustomer) cc
on
 cc.CompanyId = i.CompanyID and
 cc.rn = ((i.rn - 1) / 10000) + 1
```

Comment: Hi Damien, this is allocating 1 invoice to every customer. My apologies if my question is not clear, Basically I am trying to allocate 10,000 invoices to 50 customers for every company. Every company in the database has 500,000 invoices and I am trying to spread that across 50 customers within each organisation. In total I have 5, million invoices.

Comment: @John - it shouldn't be. The invoices numbered 1-10000 via that `ROW_NUMBER` expression should have 1 subtracted (0-9999). Divide by 10000 (all are now 0) and add 1 (all are now 1). All of those rows should be matched to the first customer. (I've added a pair of brackets I missed though)

Comment: Thanks Damien! works now, really appreciated your help. I been struggling with this for over an hour.